# How do I get the current time using Phonegap for iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I need to get the current time. This code works perfect in a browser but does not work in a phonegap app for iOS. Is there anything I should do different within my Javascript to make this work using phonegap?

```
var dt = new Date();


        currentHours = dt.getHours();
        currentHours = ("0" + currentHours).slice(-2);
        currentMinutes = dt.getMinutes();
        currentMinutes = ("0" + currentMinutes).slice(-2);
        currentSeconds = dt.getSeconds();
        currentSeconds = ("0" + currentSeconds).slice(-2);
        var time = currentHours+":"+currentMinutes+":"+currentSeconds;


        var formData = $(this).serialize() + '&time=' + time;
```

Comment: what is the value of `time` when you print it to console?

Answer (score 3):

That has to work, check if the hour of the emulator is right (The timezone can be incorrect).

Anyway, I recommend you use the UTC timestamp like:

```
var dt = new Date();
var now = dt.getTime();
var formData = $(this).serialize() + '&time=' + now.toString();
```

Other solution is using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) lib, ex:

```
var formData = $(this).serialize() + '&time=' + moment().format("HH:MM:SS");
```

Comment: I discovered my problem. It was unrelated to the time. However, this method helped me clean up my code. Thank you for the help!